# Exclude Path from being traced in AWS X-Ray

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-xray

Tracing certain paths, like a health check, don't provide much value to us. We want to ensure we aren't paying for AWS XRay traces against health endpoints. I am trying to exclude such paths with sampling rules, but it is not working.I have attempted to use rules and setSamplingRules() without luck. I have tried using the specific url path I want to exclude as well as a wildcard like below.

```
var rules = {
"rules": [ { "description": "PostTest", "service_name": "*", 
"http_method": "*", "url_path": "*", "fixed_target": 0, "rate": 0.0 } 
],
"default": { "fixed_target": 1, "rate": 0.1 },
"version": 1
}

AWSXRay.middleware.setSamplingRules(rules);
app.use(AWSXRay.express.openSegment('app-1'));

....path
....path
....path

app.use(AWSXRay.express.closeSegment());
```

I am using the latest version of aws-xray-sdk (1.1.6).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update:
Adding debugging, I discovered that locally the rule is being matched. However, when deployed, the rule is not being matched. The issue is that the health endpoint is being called via the Rancher healthcheck container, which does not provide a service name - it is undefined. Thus, it does not match the rule with the 'service_name'='*'.

Reply:
This seems to be a bug with the AWS X-Ray SDK for Node.js. An undefined host header should indeed match the wildcard character.

This has been fixed in the latest version.

Forums post addressing issue here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=269425&tstart=0

Answer (score 1):

### You can setup the sampling rules from the trace settings

[image: Sampling rules for preventing traces]

[image: Criteria of sampling rules]

Here's how you can set up sampling rules in AWS X-Ray:

1. **Open the AWS X-Ray Console**: Go to the AWS Management Console and open the X-Ray service.
2. **Navigate to Sampling Rules**: In the X-Ray console, navigate to the "Sampling rules" section. This is where you can define and manage your sampling rules.
3. **Create a New Sampling Rule**:

- Click on the "Create rule" button to create a new sampling rule.
- Define the conditions for the rule, such as HTTP method, URL path, host, etc. You can use wildcards (*) to match multiple values.
- Specify the sampling rate or fixed target for the rule. This determines how many requests matching the conditions should be traced.
- You can also set other optional parameters such as priority, description, etc., to further customize the rule.
  Save the Rule: Once you have defined the sampling rule, click on the "Save" or "Create" button to save the rule.

4. **Verify and Monitor**: After saving the sampling rule, you can verify that it's active and monitor its behavior in the X-Ray console. You can also adjust the sampling rules as needed based on your application's requirements and performance characteristics.

Here are some important points to keep in mind:

- AWS X-Ray sampling rules are evaluated in order of priority, so make sure to set the priorities appropriately if you have multiple rules that may overlap.
- You can create sampling rules based on various attributes such as HTTP method, URL path, host, service name, etc., allowing for fine-grained control over tracing behavior.
- Sampling rules provide flexibility in defining both fixed-rate and reservoir-based sampling strategies, allowing you to balance trace coverage and overhead based on your application's needs.

By configuring sampling rules in AWS X-Ray, you can control which requests are traced and ensure that you capture sufficient data for analysis while minimizing the performance overhead of tracing.