# AWS X Ray Configuration to not track one endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I have an application that uses AWS X-Ray. One of my endpoints is a GET request only for checking the health status. I don't want this endpoint to be monitored by AWS X-Ray. How can I achieve this?

This is my web config:

```
package com.poc.clientserviceapi.config;
import com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRay;
import com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRayRecorderBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.xray.jakarta.servlet.AWSXRayServletFilter;
import com.amazonaws.xray.strategy.jakarta.SegmentNamingStrategy;
import com.amazonaws.xray.strategy.sampling.LocalizedSamplingStrategy;
import jakarta.servlet.Filter;
import com.amazonaws.xray.slf4j.SLF4JSegmentListener;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import java.net.URL;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {
    @Bean
    public Filter TracingFilter() {
        AWSXRayRecorderBuilder builder = AWSXRayRecorderBuilder
                .standard().withSegmentListener(new SLF4JSegmentListener("CUSTOM-PREFIX"));

        URL ruleFile = WebConfig.class.getResource("/sampling-rules.json");
        builder.withSamplingStrategy(new LocalizedSamplingStrategy(ruleFile));

        AWSXRay.setGlobalRecorder(builder.build());

        return new AWSXRayServletFilter(SegmentNamingStrategy.dynamic("Scorekeep"));
    }
}
```

I have already tried this:

```
package com.poc.clientserviceapi.config;
import com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRay;
import com.amazonaws.xray.AWSXRayRecorderBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.xray.jakarta.servlet.AWSXRayServletFilter;
import com.amazonaws.xray.strategy.sampling.LocalizedSamplingStrategy;
import jakarta.servlet.*;
import com.amazonaws.xray.slf4j.SLF4JSegmentListener;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public Filter TracingFilter() {
        AWSXRayRecorderBuilder builder = AWSXRayRecorderBuilder
                .standard().withSegmentListener(new SLF4JSegmentListener("CUSTOM-PREFIX"));

        URL ruleFile = WebConfig.class.getResource("/sampling-rules.json");
        builder.withSamplingStrategy(new LocalizedSamplingStrategy(ruleFile));

        AWSXRay.setGlobalRecorder(builder.build());

        return new MyAWSXRayServletFilter();
    }

    @WebFilter("/*")
    public static class MyAWSXRayServletFilter implements Filter {

        private final String ignoredEndpointPath = "/sqs/health";

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

            // Ignore the specified endpoint
            if (!request.getRequestURI().equals(ignoredEndpointPath)) {
                AWSXRayServletFilter tracingFilter = new AWSXRayServletFilter();
                tracingFilter.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain);
            } else {
                filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void destroy() {
        }
    }
}
```

but then I starting to face another types of issues, as:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: The AWSXRayServletFilter requires either a fixedName init-param or an instance of SegmentNamingStrategy. Add an init-param tag to the AWSXRayServletFilter's declaration in web.xml, using param-name: 'fixedName'. Alternatively, pass an instance of SegmentNamingStrategy to the AWSXRayServletFilter constructor.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rule out health check by configuring sampling rules https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-sampling.html

Answer (score 0):

I kept my first WebConfig and changed my sampling-rules.json:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "default": {
    "fixed_target": 1,
    "rate": 0.05
  },
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Ignore /sqs/health endpoint",
      "service_name": "*",
      "http_method": "*",
      "url_path": "/sqs/health",
      "host": "*",
      "fixed_target": 0,
      "rate": 0.0
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting up sampling rules from trace settings.

You can also refer to this answer.

[Exclude Path from being traced in AWS X-Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798328/exclude-path-from-being-traced-in-aws-x-ray/78056067#78056067)